# Visual Studio Pro 2012: local db connection keeps closing

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012

I've tried searching for this, but it would seem as if I'm the only person having this problem.  For my project in Visual Studio Pro 2012, the database connection keeps dropping constantly.  Seems to be almost random, as sometimes just clicking to open a table will cause it to close, or even just writing a new SQL query.  Sometimes it will even close right after I click to open it.

I poked around in 'modify connection' and didn't see much that would help, but I tried upping the connection retries to 10. Which doesn't help, and apparently isn't saving either, because it was back at 1 when I checked again.

It doesn't make sense - because I recently transitioned from a virtual machine running locally, to using Amazon Workspaces.  None of the data or settings were migrated over.  Also, a coworker has the same exact setup, and he never has problems.  We are working on the same project, using the same database.

Anyone have any ideas?  It is highly irritating.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are using localdb, and attaching to a file?  You aren't connecting to a database on another Amazon Workspace?